# How to change the password of membership table in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I want to change the password of Membership table ,i can change directly in database but that is in encrypted format.how to retrieve original password in front end and How to update that .Please send me the logic.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Are passwords stored in [**Hashed** or **Encrypted**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.passwordformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? Do you want to reset the password without asking for Secret Question and Answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directory change it in database and should use Membership provided methods.

```
using System.Web.Security;


u = Membership.GetUser("username1");
u.ChangePassword("OldPassword","NewPass");
```

If you don't know old pass, use MembershipUser.ResetPassword instead

Answer (score 1):

If you want a ready-made solution, I use this tool to manage my users and roles.

You just fire it up and point it to the web.config of your web app and away you go.

http://aspnetmemberman.codeplex.com/

**Features**

- Initialize membership databases
- Create and delete users
- Create and delete roles
- Assign and un-assign users to roles
- Reset user passwords
- Unlock, activate and de-activate users
- Works with System.Web and custom providers
- Attempts to handle custom profiles